# My check box does not show the feature layer

Tags: javascript, checkbox, arcgis-js-api, esri-maps

Here is my code

```
else if(which == "abc"){  
        var d = (id).toString();  
        d = d.replace("abc", "");  
        query.where = "Name='" + d + "'";  
        console.info(query.where);  
        query.returnGeometry = true;  
        layerC.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function (features) {  
          thePoly = features[0].geometry;  
          theExtent = thePoly.getExtent().expand(1); //Zoom out slightly from the polygon's extent  
          map.setExtent(theExtent);  
        }); 

    }
     var text;
     var R = document.getElementById('abc').value;
     var rLyrToggle = dom.byId("rLyr");

     switch(Cpt) {
case "room1":
    on(rLyrToggle, "change", function() {
      building layer.visible = rLyrToggle.checked;

    });
    break;

default:
    text = "No room";
}
```

My check box does not show the layer upon checking layer is added to the map but I disable its visibilty ,
I want that when combox selected value is equal to the case 1 then the feature is visibile when user check the box

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle where we can reproduce same issue.. that will be a better way...however somewhere its fishy in switch case..   building layer.visible = rLyrToggle.checked; on this line... if you want a exact fix then add some more details or similar running environment..

Comment: Fishy? i have added layer to the map but sets its visibilty tot false .when combox value matches the case number it has that file so when user click the check box the said layer is visibile

Comment: or is there any example that user select the layer from dropdown button. it is cascading nested filtering

Comment: whatever you have conveyed in above msgs is it feasible to create a running sample similar to it..

Comment: i cannot create running sample :(

Comment: Its quite difficult to help if you don't want to help yourself.. let me try

Comment: any idea about getting all values of the field instead of distinct value like  esriRequest({
              url: "http://localhost:6080/arcgis/rest/services/query?where=First_Name ='" + id.toString() + "'&outFields=Last_Name&returnGeometry=false&orderByFields=Last_Name&returnDistinctValues=true&f=json",
              content:{
                f:'json'
              }, in this example query returns unique values i want to return all values

Comment: sure... we can do it..

Comment: how ? i tried with distinct values it returns few values . i want to populate with all values.

Comment: added an example/answer for finding all/partial value from a gis layer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to find all value(As mentioned in comments) from a GIS layer i Would suggest use **`queryTask`** instead of **`esriRequest`**-

Below is the working code-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Query State Info without Map</title>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
    <script>
      require([
        "dojo/dom", "dojo/on",
        "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function (dom, on, Query, QueryTask) {

        var queryTask = new QueryTask("https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/5");

        var query = new Query();
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = [
          "SQMI", "STATE_NAME", "STATE_FIPS", "SUB_REGION", "STATE_ABBR",
          "POP2000", "POP2007", "POP00_SQMI", "POP07_SQMI", "HOUSEHOLDS",
          "MALES", "FEMALES", "WHITE", "BLACK", "AMERI_ES", "ASIAN", "OTHER",
          "HISPANIC", "AGE_UNDER5", "AGE_5_17", "AGE_18_21", "AGE_22_29",
          "AGE_30_39", "AGE_40_49", "AGE_50_64", "AGE_65_UP"
        ];

        on(dom.byId("execute"), "click", execute);
        on(dom.byId("findAll"), "click", findAll);

        function execute () {
          query.where = "";
          query.text = dom.byId("stateName").value;
          queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
        }
        
        function findAll () {
          query.where = "1=1";
          queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
        }

        function showResults (results) {
          var resultItems = [];
          var resultCount = results.features.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
            var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
            for (var attr in featureAttributes) {
              resultItems.push("<b>" + attr + ":</b>  " + featureAttributes[attr] + "<br>");
            }
            resultItems.push("<br>");
          }
          dom.byId("info").innerHTML = resultItems.join("");
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    US state name :
    <input type="text" id="stateName" value="California">
    <input id="execute" type="button" value="Get Details">
     OR
    <input id="findAll" type="button" value="Find All">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="info" style="padding:5px; margin:5px; background-color:#eee;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: if  i want to return text value from the attribute table and populate these value in comobo box . then how it has to be done>

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong.. You want to fetch all the unique value of a single attribut/field and populate those value to a combo box... Correct?

Comment: It will be great if you can add a new question and let me know the link...

Comment: yes. but now these are just text value return type html

Comment: your comments are quite confusing.. it will be better if u can explain the exact requirement.. .however what exactly mean by this (these are just text value return type html )

Comment: sorry . i meant these are text values

Comment: what about this problem?

Comment: you are not able to create a sample so everytime i have to write from scratch for u.. so it may take time to crate a sample or create a new question so anyone can help you...